# UITableView with a UIView underneath the Cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableView and below the custom cell (in IB) I have inserted a UIView. The UIView gets set to hidden when viewDidLoad() gets called and is only displayed when there is no data in the UITableView. This works great and servers my purpose.

The problem is that even when the UIView is hidden, the scrolling on the UITableView considers the view to be present. i.e. The vertical scroll with scroll well below the last cell, covering the area where the UIView exists - even though its blank and nothing is displayed.

I have tried to hide the UIView but this doesn't help either. How do I get the scroll to not extend to the area covered by the UIView?

Edit:

[image: IB View] [image: Vertical scroll below last cell - view is hidden]

The image on the left is how IB looks. I have added a UIView as a subview of the TableView. The image on the right is the large scroll space below the last cell.

Expected behavior: When the view is hidden, the scroll view only scrolls until the last cell.

Comment: Try making the height of the view 0 instead of hiding it.

Comment: Important distinction: You say your view is "below" the custom cell in IB. You don't have it as another prototype cell, do you?

Comment: Also, could you clarify the passage "The vertical scroll with scroll well below the last cell, covering the area where the UIView exists - even though its blank and nothing is displayed"? It seems like you may have put a word in there that doesn't belong.

Comment: @ErikKerber yes, its not another prototype cell. Its a subview inside the UITableView.

What I mean is that the scroll action allows the user to scroll vertically past the last cell (a considerable amount). If I reduce the height of the view, the scrolling amount decreases which indicated that the scroll bounds were set to cover the UIView in spite of the view being hidden.

Comment: @wholly_cow I think at this point you would be best off providing a screenshot of what you are seeing vs. what you are expecting. As long as your view is simply a subview of UITableView, and you aren't manually trying to alter the contentSize, then the view shouldn't affect contentSize or scrollability.

Comment: @rdelmar i tried that and it doesn't accept a 0 height.

    self.noDataView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0);
    [self.noDataView setNeedsDisplay];

makes no difference

Comment: @wholly_cow Are you using autolayout? Setting the frame is a NO-OP if you are using autolayout.

Comment: @ErikKerber - yes, I'm using auto-layout. That now makes sense as to why I cant set the frame.

Comment: @wholly_cow Sorry, too many things could be going on. I suggest downloading Reveal (revealapp.com) and inspecting the content size at runtime.  Try deleting the subview and seeing if it's still broken, then re-add it. Try deleting all constraints around that view. Who knows what goofy thing is going on. The certain thing is that your UITableView contentSize is bigger than it should be.

Comment: @ErikKerber Thanks! - revealapp looks neat. Will give it a go. I think its just that the scrolling limits are set before viewDidLoad() is called. Hence the scrolling limits assume the noDataView to be present. I think I'm closing in on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is displayed only when there is no cells, you could just add it over your UITableView (or behind it if your UITableView's background is clear) and hide it when you have cells to display.  Just be sure to add your view as a sibling of your UITableView and not as a child view of your UITableView.

Comment: IB doesn't allow me to add it as a sibling to the UITableView. It only accepts it as a sibling to the UIViewController or a child of the UITableView

Comment: I did a quick test and adding the view as a child of the tableView also works.  In my test, I positioned the view in the center of the tableView with `myView.center = self.tableView.center`.

Comment: Weird - could you take a look at my screenshots. Does yours look like the IB one on the left?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't putting your view as the tableView's footer view ?  Adding a view as a subview of UITableView shouldn't have any impact on the contentSize since your view is basically floating over the content.  There must be something goofy going on.

Comment: Do you know how the UITableView's auto scrolling calculates its scroll bounds?

I'm wondering if after I make the UIView hidden I can ask it to re-calculate its bounds?

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView that uses his delegate & dataSource to fill its content view and calculate its contentSize.  I suggest you to try Reveal App, you will be able to see your view hierarchy at run time with their respective frames.  Maybe that will help you see what is wrong.